# Does Amazon allow raising the SES mail *receiving* limits?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

I run an email forwarding service (https://kopi.cloud). 
I'm investigating the feasibility of building a feature to allow users to "bring their own domain".
It seems like this should work fine with SES, except there are limits on total number of rules and total number of recipients (see https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/limits.html)

With the currently limits on rules and recipients, I could pack the subscriber domains into the receipt rules and Kopi could support up to about 10,000 separate domains.

10K domains will be plenty for a while, I don't expect that many people will actually want to bring their own domain (I reckon most people who'd want this would just go ahead and do their own forwarding), so I'm going to go ahead prototyping the feature.

But I need to check if these limits are "soft limits", like the sending limits that can be raised on request; or "hard limits", where no increase is possible.

I'm still going to prototype the feature and if it were to be wildly successful, I guess I could jury-rig something together with multiple accounts or some other shennanigans.

So my question: "Is it possible to get the SES receiving rule limits raised?"

Comment: Not sure if this question belongs here...? IDK.

Comment: why not open an AWS support ticket to ask?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from AWS support, as of June 2019 - "these limits are a hard limit and cannot be increased at the moment".

There is an outstanding request to raise them though.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=303902